# field "to" in deploy contract transaction

Tags: transactions, contract-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a contract using MEW toward Ganache.

When deploying a contract should the "to" field be included? 
if the answer is yes, what value should it contain?

is there an official documentation that defines this behavior?

Thank you

Comment: Can you tell me where you see this to in "deploy contract" - there should be no "to" and I was just verifying again and only see Byte Code and gas limit as is to be expected

Comment: the "to" is inside the transaction generated:

i downloaded MEW version 3.11.2.1 , and the steps that i did are: 
access "contract" section > deploy contract > insert bytecode > sign transaction with private key > 2 textareas appear, the left one shows the readable transaction with the "to" field, empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to` should indeed be empty (in reality it's `0` in the encoded transaction).

The [Yellow Paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf) is the definitive source, but this blog post might help as an overview: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/09/how-smart-contract-deployment-works/. (It might make sense to go back and also read our post about transactions in general, which is linked near the top.)